# Sent email with PHPMailer gets stuck in SMTP queue folder

Tags: php, smtp, windows-server-2012

I have a form on my website that sends the results to a specific email address. The form works just fine (I think) but the emails get stuck in the queue folder server side. I have the SMTP server set to no authentication and it's set to allow connection from all IPs. Port 25 is also open.

There are no reported events in the Server Manager Event log and I don't see anything reported in the SMTP logs. When I telnet to send an email and the same thing happens. The email is sent but it gets stuck in the queue folder.

Here is a section of the SMTP logs:

```
#Date: 2014-01-09 15:14:31
#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-sitename s-computername s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken cs-version cs-host cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) 
2014-01-09 15:14:31 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 HELO - +i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com 250 0 33 43 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:14:31 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 MAIL - +FROM:<dbass@interactive360.com> 250 0 49 36 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:14:31 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 RCPT - +TO:<dbass@interactive360.com> 250 0 37 34 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:14:31 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 DATA - +<43d1d1eccd3453e5a8c44089d756075e@www.interactive360.com> 250 0 141 16333 15 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:14:31 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 QUIT - i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com 240 15 58 4 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:16:14 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 HELO - +i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com 250 0 33 43 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:16:14 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 MAIL - +FROM:<dbass@interactive360.com> 250 0 49 36 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:16:14 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 RCPT - +TO:<dbass@interactive360.com> 250 0 37 34 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:16:14 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 DATA - +<18cb24d6e70e9c3bd553afb56e7fb88f@www.interactive360.com> 250 0 141 16333 32 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:16:14 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 QUIT - i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com 240 32 58 4 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:23:05 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 HELO - +i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com 250 0 33 43 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:23:05 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 MAIL - +FROM:<dbass@interactive360.com> 250 0 49 36 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:23:05 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 RCPT - +TO:<dbass@interactive360.com> 250 0 37 34 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:23:05 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 DATA - +<a1e1efef337e951b5f023df8d3efba7b@www.interactive360.com> 250 0 141 16329 31 SMTP - - - -
2014-01-09 15:23:05 127.0.0.1 i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com SMTPSVC1 I360NONAUTOWEB 127.0.0.1 0 QUIT - i360NonAutoWeb.corp.interactive360.com 240 31 58 4 0 SMTP - - - -
```

Here is my PHP form:

```
<?php

 require_once('assets/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

 $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $job = $_POST['job'];
 $file = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];


 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->From = "dbass@interactive360.com";
 $mail->FromName  =  "Interactive 360 Job Form";
 $mail->AddAddress("dbass@interactive360.com","Job Form");

 $mail->WordWrap = 50;  

 $mail->Subject = "Interactive 360 Job Form";
 $mail->Body="
            First Name: $first_name
            Last Name: $last_name
            Phone Number: $phone
            Email: $email
            Job: $job";

 $maxsize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
 $types = array('application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');


 if ((isset($_FILES['fileUpload']) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['size'] < $maxsize && in_array( $_FILES['fileUpload']['type'], $types)) 
 {
  $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
 } 
 else 
 {
  header("Refresh: 3; URL=http://www.interactive360.com/join-our-team.php");
  echo 'Please upload a PDF or Word Document that is under 2MB';
  exit();
 }

 $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) 
 {
   header("Refresh: 3; URL=http://www.interactive360.com/join-our-team.php");
   echo 'Please enter a valid email address';
   exit();
 }

 if($first_name == '') 
 {
   header("Refresh: 2; URL=http://www.interactive360.com/join-our-team.php");
   echo 'Please enter your first name';
   exit();
 }

 if($last_name == '') 
 {
   header("Refresh: 2; URL=http://www.interactive360.com/join-our-team.php");
   echo 'Please enter your last name';
   exit();
 }

 if(!$mail->Send())
 {
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 }
 else
 {
   header("Refresh: 2; URL=http://www.interactive360.com/");
   echo 'Thank you for your feedback.';
 }    
?>
```

Comment: I believe PHPMailer defaults to using the PHP mail() function, which in turn uses sendmail by default, instead of SMTP.  I don't see in your code that you specified it to use SMTP.  Did you set `$mail->IsSMTP()` and not include it in the code above?  If not, perhaps that should be tried.

Comment: You are correct on both assumptions. Previously, I had included $mail->isSMTP(); but the same problem still occurred.